# .net core MVC - specifying a layout view in a controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there not way to specify a layout view in a controller directly? Thereby keeping my views clean of C# code.

I tried this, but no luck. Some advice says I need a model. But what if I have no model to pass?

```
return View("AboutMe", "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml");
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on what you're trying to do? because for example you can add a `_Layout.cshtml` in every folder under a controller name and get different layout for each controller. So the conventional way of picking up the layout might help you.

Comment: I didnt know that. But I know this must be possible. To select a custom layout for a page.

Answer (score 3):

You can change your layout dynamically; by using `ViewData` or adding a property to the ViewModel.

using `ViewData` :

Controller :

```
ViewData["Layout"] = "~/Path to your custom layout.cshtml"
```

View :

```
@ {
    Layout = ViewData["Layout"];
}
```

Comment: ```ViewData["Layout"] = "_Layout2.cshtml";```

This isnt working. It shows my old layout.

Niether is:  ```ViewData["Layout"] = "_Layout2";```

Comment: @LinuxMan1820 Did you also update the view to set the Layout equal to `ViewData["Layout"]` ? You have to do both for it to work.

Comment: @LinuxMan1820 Is the layout in the same folder? If not, you need to specify the path e.g. `ViewData["Layout"] = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout2.cshtml";`

Comment: I dont want anything in the view file. Just raw html. It is a .cshtml file though.

Comment: Also in my normal layout view file there is nothing like that. Why should there be in layout2?

Comment: @derloopkat that was the first thing I did, it still shows the default layout.

Comment: Also, there is NO MasterName in my View. It gives an error when I try to use it.

Comment: This overload `return View("ViewName", "_customLayout", model)` belongs to ASP.NET MVC. It doesn't exist in ASP.NET Core.

Comment: @HMZ thats what I was assuming. Any thoughts on how to select a custom layout from within a controller?

Comment: @LinuxMan1820 Your only way is to use the `ViewData` option. i.e, `ViewData["Layout"] = "~/The path of your view"` then in your view you do `@{ Layout = ViewData["Layout"] }`. Also, i don't get what you're doing. Razor is a templating engine and was made to mix c# with html so not wanting c# in a `cshtml` file isn't exactly being clean in addition to not being useful.

Comment: @HMZ whats the point of doing it in the controller if I am forced to always do it in the view? My hope was top-down control.

Comment: @LinuxMan1820 Using the `ViewData` approach, you can for example assign a layout to resulting view based on a specific condition in your controller. Other than that, its just a single line in your view. No code needed in your controller.